# Check for existing association 'belongs_to' in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user, :order_status, :delivery_type, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Before creating a new order I need to check if User with user_id from params exists; I can get   any user_id, and it may be for nonexistent User. Is it possible to check existing through model validations or I must do it manually? Thanks.

Comment: i believe you do need any more validation for that as you are already validating user presence so if you somehow pass user_id: 256 (assume that 256 is not exists for user) than you will see the error message  User can't be blank, because it is validating user presence not the user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`validates_associated`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated) to validate the associated object as follows:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user, :order_status, :delivery_type, presence: true
  belongs_to :user

  validates_associated :user
end
```

Note that you should not remove the `presence` validation even if you add `validates_associated :user`.  Please see the following note from the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated):

> NOTE: This validation will not fail if the association hasn’t been
>   assigned. If you want to ensure that the association is both present
>   and guaranteed to be valid, you also need to use
>   validates_presence_of.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Order.reflect_on_association(:user)`, more details please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646800/check-if-association-exists-without-incurring-a-database-hit/51589738#answer-51589738)