# Check if association exists without incurring a database hit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Is there a way to check if an ActiveRecord's `belongs_to` association exists without incurring a database query.

I'm using `example_association.present?` to check and it results in the association being loaded if it does.

All I want to know is if the association exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reflect_on_all_associations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations) as:

```
Foo.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name).include?(:example_assoc)
```

Where `:example_assoc` is one of the `belongs_to` association.

Or if you have an instance of model class:

```
@foo.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name).include?(:example_assoc)
```

Comment: Reading now I realise what the question really was. I though the question was "if there are any associated objects".

Answer (score 1):

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Check if the association exist by:

```
Article.reflect_on_association(:pages)
```

or

```
Page.reflect_on_association(:article)
```

If the association not exist, the return value of `Page.reflect_on_association(:article)` will be `nil`, otherwise it puts like :

```
#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection:0x00007fbe099d9c10
@active_record=
  Page(id: integer, name: string),
    @association_scope_cache={},
    @automatic_inverse_of=false,
    @constructable=true,
    @foreign_type="article_type",
    @klass=nil,
    @name=:article,
    @options={:autosave=>true},
    @plural_name="articles",
    @scope=nil,
    @scope_lock=#<Thread::Mutex:0x00007fbe099d9990>,
    @type=nil>
```

It mains the association exist,and you can get more info about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to minimise the number of queries perhaps you should consider using "include" to eager load the associations.

Eg.

```
foos = Foo.includes(:example_associations).all
```

And then later in a loop or something when invoking

```
foo.example_associations.present?
```

Should not invoke any additional database queries

Comment: This is not the case, as includes generates a left outer join on Foo, meaning it will always include Foo, and return nil on :example_associations if Foo does not have one.